# Django Framework - Filling models

Tags: python, django

Does it possible to auto fill fields in same table with identical data without filling it with same data separately in Django Framework?

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   first_phone = models.CharField() # <-- user fills only single input: 12345
   second_phone = models.CharField() # <-- auto set using field: first_phone
   third_phone = models.CharField() # <-- auto set using field: first_phone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can override in save() method.

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   first_phone = models.CharField() # <-- user fills only single input: 12345
   second_phone = models.CharField() # <-- auto set using field: first_phone
   third_phone = models.CharField()

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       phone = self.first_phone

       self.second_phone = phone
       self.third_phone = phone
       super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yes save() method helps. But how prevent second_phone and third_phone input?

Comment: You can exclude both fields .Can you show your views ?